# Contact moderators for little things

Tags: support, status-completed, moderation, moderator-abilities, contact

There are a lot of questions, with answers, about how to contact a moderator about a lot of stuff.

But no way to just give a moderator a heads up about some things. There are flagging options on many things, and deletion things on others.

To put it strait-out, on SO, I was looking through tags, and I found one that said jqeury. Me being me, at a glance I thought it said jquery. I didnt notice it was not the same, although I did feel something was wrong, like this tag should already have a description.

I went ahead and wrote a description for it, and submitted it. I don't enough reputation for the description to take effect immediately, so it didn't show up, and was waiting to be approved.

So what I'm asking, is when something like this happens again, which it will, what do I do?

Should I just wait for it to be checked, or is there some way to send a message to a moderator giving them a heads up that I just screwed something up?

Comment: `is there some way to send a message to a moderator giving them a heads up that I just screwed something up?` -- You just did.

Comment: 2 approve votes from robo-reviewers already. yay!

Comment: @Wooble can you link to the suggested edit? Or was it rejected already?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2774642

Comment: As far as i can tell, it was rejected by the time I was done making this post. It still made me feel stupid though

Comment: Don't worry about it.  Two reviewers cast approval votes.  Apparently you weren't the only one that was confused.

Comment: We all screw up every now and then.

Comment: @Shade It was rejected 5 minutes after you posted this question here (as a direct result of you posting it here).

Comment: I googled it, (advanced search, not including jquery). All the results seem like typos

Comment: @apaul34208: His last two reviews don't look very good, but they were rejected by others, and the next dozen or so approvals look fine.  I guess he just doesn't cast reject votes.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Perhaps lock/archive this question? I count it as completed.